# Karate DSL blank response passes tests

Tags: rest, cucumber, karate

I'm a bit perplexed why my tests are passing. I'm doing some assertions on what I believe the response should return. I'm getting a successful 200 status and an empty response. All the following assertions are passing though:

```
    When method get
    * print response
    Then status 200
    And match response == '#notnull'
    And match each $[*] == { caption : '#string' }
    And match each $[*] contains { source : '#object' }
    And match each $[*].source contains {channels : '#present' }
    And match each $[*] contains { post : '#object' }
```

Test output:

```
12:59:30.258 [main] INFO  com.dataminr.karate - [print] [
]

1 Scenarios (1 passed)
14 Steps (14 passed)
0m2.539s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `match each` will always pass on an empty array. Think of it like multiplying something by 0.

Just add this:

```
And match response != []
```

or:

```
And match response != '#[0]'
```

Comment: Appreciate it, Peter. I did add a check for 
```And match response != []``` to fix it in my case, do you see any issues with that, or is the assertion you provided more reliable?

Comment: Just want to make sure it's correct in case someone else pops along. But I think it should be ```And match response != '#[0]'``` before the other assertions? Having it as you've described will pass as well, and I'd like to catch it before it hits the match each.