# Validate response is empty

Tags: karate

We have a 404 response that returns an empty response, but when trying to validate that, we get the following error.  Is there a suggested way to evaluate a truly empty response?

```
* if (responseStatus == 404 ) matchResult = karate.match("$ == ''")
js failed:
>>>>
01: if (responseStatus == 404 ) matchResult = karate.match("$ == ''")
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: json string can not be null or empty
- com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.Utils.notEmpty(Utils.java:401)
- com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.ParseContextImpl.parse(ParseContextImpl.java:36)
- com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.parse(JsonPath.java:647)
- com.intuit.karate.Json.of(Json.java:63)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.evalJsonPath(ScenarioEngine.java:2000)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.evalJsonPathOnVariableByName(ScenarioEngine.java:2053)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.evalKarateExpression(ScenarioEngine.java:2085)
```

Here is our response, which you can see is empty:
[image: empty response error]

We have tried the following match test, with no luck.

```
* if (responseStatus == 404 ) matchResult = karate.match("$ == ''")
* if (responseStatus == 404 ) matchResult = karate.match("$ == []")
* if (responseStatus == 404 ) matchResult = karate.match("$ == '#[0]'")
* if (responseStatus == 404 ) matchResult = karate.match("$ == '#notpresent'")
* if (responseStatus == 404 ) matchResult = karate.match("$ == '#null'")
```

Reviewed the following github posts, with no luck:
[Karate Framework : #notnull and #present are not working in case response is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56784911/karate-framework-notnull-and-present-are-not-working-in-case-response-is-emp)
[Karate DSL blank response passes tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54933406/karate-dsl-blank-response-passes-tests)

Also tried a simple match, versus a karate match with the above evaluations, but those fail as well.

```
* match $ == []
json string can not be null or empty

* match $ == {}
json string can not be null or empty

* match $ == '#notpresent'
json string can not be null or empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
* assert responseBytes.length == 0
```

Note that an empty response is *not* JSON so `$` will not work. Try:

```
* match response == ''
```

Comment: Changing to response == '' worked, but using response == '#notpresent' did not.  At least there is a working solution now.  Thank you for the clarification on $ (json) versus response (string).

Comment: @mike great ! why `#notpresent` does not work is also because it applies only to JSON. search the docs for this text: `Note that #present and #notpresent only make sense` ...